# How to get user response from a native java module on react native?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am launching a native intent from Java and I need to catch if the user saves or cancel  a configuration made before inside the java code so I could send back the corresponding response to my React Native module.

I am running the native intent `ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS` but I don't know how to catch if the user press the `save` or `cancel` button in this code.

my module code:

```java
public class MyConnection extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private Context reactContext;

    public MYConnection(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        reactContext.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        this.connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)reactContext.getSystemService(reactContext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "AndroidConnection";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void connect(String ssid,String userName, String passWord, boolean isHidden, Promise promise) {
        try
        {
          // I Config a Wifi network to save the this code
          
          int status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
          if (status == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_LIST,(ArrayList<? extends
              Parcelable>) suggestionsList);
            final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // I have try startActivityForResult but is not working cause reactContext does not have hat function
            // this.reactContext.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            this.reactContext.startActivity(intent);

            // here is where i want to check if user save or cancel to do different actions on my react native module
            promise.resolve("success");
          } else {
            promise.reject("Error creating", "Failed to add network suggestion");
          }
        } catch(e) {
          promise.reject("Error creating", e.message);
        }
}
```